# Python: "../DATA/file.csv" no longer working for file opening

Tags: python, pandas

Since a while, I have been using the short syntax ('../DAT/file.csv') to get to files under DATA folder. Since this morning, it is not working anymore and I am getting the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../DATA/file.csv'
```

Any thoughts? Code I am using is below:

Thanks in advance,

`df = pd.read_csv('../DATA/moviereviews.csv')`

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if your current directory is the one you expect it to be (i.e. the one that is beside the `DATA` directory). You can use the following to do so:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

2. Check that `DATA/moviereviews.csv` actually exists.

Comment: Hello, yes, the file actually exists and is under the folder specified. I am using now the full path using os.getcwd(). My problem is this is weird, it happens from time to time with no reason. After a restart of VSCODE it is back to work... Note I did not think that I should restart as I just opened it... maybe be a bug.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply dear, appreciate!